# How can a website stream a video without a request appearing in the network tab of the developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, request

Normally whenever I try to stream a video I can see the request when it comes through but in this case you can see the requests for a couple of images and GIFS they show beforehand as an advert but when the video comes there is no request visible. What is going on? This is true both when using Tamper data and Google Chrome developer tools

Comment: Probably some sort of steaming media, possibly via some plugin which loads the stream outside the browser.

Comment: It is using flash. In that case is there any way to see the video file on my computer?

Comment: Probably RTMP based then. That's about all I know/remember. I'm sure there are tools like WireShark which can monitor the request and probably some that can download it.